# Line break for invoice comment in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, transactional-mail

In magento while sending an invoice the commend is showing up in the same line. The line break is not working.

Please anyone help me to add line break in invoice comments.

Comment: Don't know if that could work, but since emails are in HTML, have you tried using `<br/>`'s?

Answer (score 5):

try this on transactional email invoice update

> {{var comment|nl2br}}

Answer (score 3):

It should simple work to add a HTML tag around the place you use the comments.

For some of my stores I have it like that

```
{{layout area="frontend" handle="sales_email_order_invoice_items" invoice=$invoice order=$order}}
</br>                    
</br>
<p style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 12px;color: #fff;line-height: 1.2em">{{var comment}}</p>
```

And that works fine.